Low Reynolds number flow and Potential flow
In an experiment conducted in my lab, we observed a low Reynolds number flow between two parallel plates with narrow gap between them resemble Potential Flow which is quite counter-intuitive as low Reynolds number flow are laminar flows and should not resemble potential flow. Our professor posed us the same question to be solved in the class mathematically and hasn't provided us with an answer since. I was able to come up with one idea,
"As Reynolds number decreases and approaches zero, the viscosity term tends to infinity. But since all the other terms of momentum equation are finite, viscosity has to have some finite value only. So the numerator, i.e. the Laplacion of velocity also tends to zero."
Here, I am getting a Laplace equation but it is not quite the equation that the potential flow satisfies. Thus I am stuck here. Could you please help me out.

Perhaps the situation you describe corresponds to Hele-shaw flow (two-dimensional flow). There is a Wikipedia page about this.
